# sort array accrording to current day

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Sunday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Monday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Tuesday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Wednesday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Thursday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Friday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [day_name] => Saturday
            [session_time_1] => 
        )

)
```

Sort this array according to current day name so that my current day comes first and so on.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Day of Week, e.g. Saturday, does not specify a specific date, which cannot compare to the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$day = date('l');

// Find the keywher the value found
foreach($array as $key => $v) {
    if($v->day_name == $day) {
        $found_at = $key;
        break;
    }
}

// Split the array accrodingly
$temp = array_chunk($array, $found_at);
$first = array_shift($temp);

// Merge them
$final= array();
foreach($temp as $v) {
  $final = array_merge($final, $v);
}
$final = array_merge($final, $first);
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/517418)

Comment: how to get the date from the day from current date

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use `usort` for this task and take use of `strtotime`.

Example:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a->day_name) - strtotime($b->day_name);
});
```

Comment: OP wants to sort according to current day. Like the array will start from **Friday** for today.

Comment: @Sougata yes, this does it, you can try it yourself, set your environment to wednesday or something else, it'll start from that day, till next week